# MongoDB - Grouping by a substring

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my first time working with the Aggregation framework and working with stages. I have a collection of customer documents with a lastName field. I want to return an array or collection of unique first characters in the last name. I seem to have it working with the following code:

```
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate( [

    {
        $match:
        {
            "lastName": { $exists: true }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 0,
            "initial": { $substr: [ "$lastName", 0, 1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: { $substr: [ "$initial", 0, 1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:
        {
            _id: 1
        }
    }    
    ]
);
```

My results look like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "B"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "E"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "F"
}
```

My questions are:

1. My $project maps the value to "initial". I can't figure out how to make the output use "initial" instead of _id. Does $group require _id?
2. Can someone show me a few more examples of how to achieve the same result (e.g. using .distinct(), etc.)?

Comment: Something like `{ $group: { _id:"$initial" } }`. Alternatively, you can remove the `$project` stage and pass the expression in the `$group` stage. Something like `{ $group: { _id: { $substr: [ "$lastName", 0, 1 ] } } }` followed by `{$project: { _id: 0, "initial": "$id" } }`

Comment: I see. Using `$project` _after_ `$group` allows me to create the fields I want. Makes perfect sense, thank you :-)